# Laravel prevent group parameter passing to controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm working on a Laravel 4.2 project and I have the following code:

In routes:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{subdomain}.'.Config::get('app.domain')), function(){
    Route::controller('device', 'DeviceController');
});
```

My DeviceController contains:

```
class DeviceController extends BaseController {
    public function getFoo($param1, $param2){
        return View::make('testview');
    }
}
```

When I call http://blabla.mydomain.com/device/1/2, $param1 holds blabla and $param2 holds 1.

Is there a possibility that Laravel does not pass the subdomain parameter to the controller, so $param1 becomes 1 and $param2 becomes 2.

Thank you!

Comment: Why even use the `subdomain` route parameter if you don't want it?

Comment: I use subdomain in another piece of code. This is just a simplification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to *not* pass the route group parameters to the controller function without writing your own Router classes.

*This is not really an answer to the question but rather another possible solution for the problem.*

I suggest you get the subdomain by parsing the host instead of using a route group.

```
$subdomain = null;
$host = Request::getHost();
$parts = explode('.', $host);
if(count($parts) > 2){
    $subdomain = $parts[0];
}
```

You could use this directly, write a helper function or even create a Facade for it. Whatever you like.